# why astype is not chance type of values?

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["1", "7.0", "xyz"]})
type(df.A[0])
```

the result is "str".

```
df.A = df.A.astype(int, errors = "ignore")
type(df.A[0])
```

the result is also "str". I wanna convert "1" and "7.0" to 1 and 7.

where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why astype is not chance type of values?

Because `errors = "ignore"` working different like you think.

If it failed, it return same values, so nothing  change.

If want values in numeric and `NaN` if failed:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print (df)
      A
0     1
1     7
2  <NA>
```

For mixed values - numbers with strings:

```
def num(x):
    try:
        return(int(float(x)))
    except:
        return x

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(num)
print (df)

0    1
1    7
2  xyz
```